# Sweet alert with ajax form and javascript in laravel

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

In my local project I'm trying to get response from the queries. Then I'm trying to show the notification messages via sweet alert, but I have some problems. When I try to get the response, it gets an array type mean normal text like the picture below,

[response return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxE4U.png)

My code is below:

My settings blade.php

```
<script src="/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script scr="/js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/messages_tr.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').validate();
        $('form').ajaxForm({
            beforeSubmit : function(){
            },
            success:function (response) {
                    swal(
                        response.baslik,
                        response.icerik,
                        response.durum

                    )

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My controller.php

```
$ayarlar = ayarlar::where('id',1)->update($request->all());
if($ayarlar) {
return response(['baslik'=>'Başarılı','icerik'=>'Kayıt 
Başarılı','durum'=>'success']);
}else {
return response(['baslik'=>'Başarılı','icerik'=>'Kayıt 
Başarılı','durum'=>'error']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to fix; response type select json.

return response()->json(['baslik'=>'Başarılı','icerik'=>'Kayıt 
Başarılı','durum'=>'success']);

add datatype for ajax

```
$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit : function(){},
    dataType : "json",
    success:function (response) {
        swal(
            response.baslik,
            response.icerik,
            response.durum
        );
    }
});
```

or change succes function

```
success:function (response) {
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    swal(
        response.baslik,
        response.icerik,
        response.durum
    );
}
```

Comment: it will solve your problem. If the problem persists, you can send a private message in Turkish. @sadri